# Enabling text file logging for WinSCP script

Tags: logging, winscp

Hi have a WinSCP script to put a file on remote server using SFTP, which is working fine. But I would enable logging to a text file on a local directory.

I have the following script

```
option batch on
option confirm off

# connect minute session
open sftp://xyz.com:22/ -privatekey=E:\PK\*.ppk

# force binary mode transfer
option transfer ascii

# navigate to mediacom and put file
lcd "E:\export\"
cd /mediacom/testdir
put "CI_Tst.tab"

# disconnect daily session
close

# exit WinScP
exit
```

Many I know how I can log results of above script to a local file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable logging, use the [`/log=` command-line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging) switch of WinSCP:

```
winscp.com /script=C:\path\to\script.txt /log=C:\path\to\script.log
```

---

You can use patterns like `!Y-!M-!D-!T-!P` to make the filename unique.
See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_logging#session_log