# WinSCP SSH error Unknown command 'ssh-rsa'

Tags: powershell, ssh, sftp, file-transfer, winscp

**Context:** I have CSV files I'm outputting from SQL Server through BCP. I'm trying to securely transfer the files to a remote SFTP folder using WinSCP.

**Details:** When I execute the batch file below through powershell I raise an error 'Unknown command 'ssh-rsa' with the log file showing an exit code = 1 which is failure.

Here is what my synchronization file looks like...

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://username:password@sftp.redacted.com -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 redacted=ssh-rsa 2048 redacted"
synchronize remote D:\redactedDaily_Reports\redacted_Catalog_New_Item /upload/redacted_catalog
exit
```

and & my batch file...

```
winscp.com /script=SyncTo_redacted_catalog.txt /log=D:\redacted_Daily_Reports\winscp_log_catalog.txt
pause
```

Here is a snippet of my powershell output and log file...
[powershell output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJl23.png)

```
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.379 Access granted
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.379 Opening session as main channel
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.447 Opened main channel
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.583 Started a shell/command
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.583 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.584 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.584 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2019-03-06 23:39:28.584 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 95, Number: -1
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 Unknown server extension posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 Supports statvfs@openssh.com extension version "2"
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 Unknown server extension fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 Limiting packet size to OpenSSH sftp-server limit of 262148 bytes
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 Getting current directory name.
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 Getting real path for '.'
> 2019-03-06 23:39:28.769 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 10, Number: 16
< 2019-03-06 23:39:28.837 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 23, Number: 16
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.837 Real path is '/'
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.837 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2019-03-06 23:39:28.837 Script: Active session: [1] redacted@sftp.redacted.com
> 2019-03-06 23:39:28.838 Script: ssh-rsa 2048 redacted
< 2019-03-06 23:39:28.838 Script: Unknown command 'ssh-rsa'.
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.838 Script: Failed
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.838 Script: Exit code: 1
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.838 Closing connection.
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.838 Sending special code: 12
. 2019-03-06 23:39:28.838 Sent EOF message
```

**Questions:** 
**Why am I raising this error & how do I fix it?** 
Is this error trying to tell me that I'm using an incorrect key-fingerprint -- If so, why is that the case when a) I obtained this key directly from the server when I connected successfully the first time and b) the log file appears to show the initial connection was successful?

**Please help** Any tips or recommendations greatly appreciated -- responses will probably reach a decent sized audience given that winscp is a pretty popular utility. I've done my research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304915/enabling-text-file-logging-for-winscp-script), [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_verifying_the_host_key), [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey), [here](https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Troubleshooting-SSH-Issues), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3wBJgmXZUg&t=13s), [here](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=90533#90533) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndvEYOQLc4c) & haven't found a suitable solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is nonsense:
`-hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 redacted=ssh-rsa 2048 redacted"`
*(where have you seen such a strange syntax?)*

It should be like:
`-hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="`

Though it does not really explain the error message you are getting – unless there are some special characters (like double quotes) in the `redacted` part.

---

In general, the easiest way is to [have WinSCP GUI generate correct script template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) for you.

---

Or, if you want to go a manual way, see:
[Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey#automation)
Particularly the section *"Automatic host key verification"* (though you will want to read the article from the beginning).

*I'm aware that you refer to this article yourself. But then I do not understand how you could have arrived to your strange syntax.*

Comment: Where exactly did you copy the host key (in that format) from?

Comment: *"I've tried several variations including the one you recommended and I'm still raising that error"* - Show us a **complete** log file for that. -- Note that a fingerprint of a **public** host key is a **public** information - no need to "redact" it - you only make it complicated for us to help you by doing so.

Comment: Are you sure? Don't you actually get **two lines** into the clipboard? 1) `ssh-rsa 2048 Wbe5LyFm08qfvhCX+KGULKiRl/qXp4C5/zez5Tw3zIA=` and 2) `ssh-rsa 2048 ad:b3:c7:a1:ff:43:5c:71:d6:a7:50:6c:1a:c8:d1:70`?

Comment: You can use both, but the first one (SHA-256 fingerprint - the one *without colons*) is the more secure one.